# Rails routing - how to add .html extension to the routing rule?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this rule:

```
  match '*urlnames' => 'home#searching_names'
```

The URL address looks like **website.com/john.html**.
The problem is, that in the log I see

```
  Parameters: {"urlnames"=>"john"}
```

without the `.html` extension. Text extension is important, I would need to test it in the controller.
I tried to add to the routing rule this part:

```
  match '*urlnames' => 'home#searching_names', :defaults => { :format => "html" }
```

But still the same, in the log is

```
Parameters: {"urlnames"=>"john"}
```

How can I catch the extension in the controller?

Comment: What does `rake routes` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the requested format via `request.parameters[:format]` or (as a MIME type) via `request.format`.

However, you can also use a `respond_to` block:

```
def show
  file = params[:urlnames]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { ... }
    format.txt  { ... }
  end
end
```

where `...` is code to render some text, or send some data or a file.

If you're just trying to show some static files, just place them in the public dir, and bypass Rails entirely.